# drag the element in the drop box in jQuery

Tags: jquery

i have used the jQuery page layout. now i drag the elements to the page dropable by this code

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery(".component").draggable({
  //  use a helper-clone that is append to 'body' so is not 'contained' by a pane
    helper:  function () { return jQuery(this).clone().appendTo('body').css('zIndex',5).show(); },
    cursor:  'move'
  });

  jQuery('.ui-layout-center').droppable({ 
     accept:  '.component',
     drop:  function () { show('.component') }
  }); 
});
```

but now i cant drag the dropable element in the page again. did i make any mistake in that code.

Comment: I get a JavaScript error with the above code as the function _show_ is undefined. Is it a custom function or are you wanting to use jQuery's [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this template for your Dragable elements

```
$(".component").draggable({     
    revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
    containment: "#Content", // stick to demo-frame if present               
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move"
});
```

Comment: it did not work. i checked it earlier and i think it should not be use here.

Answer (score 0):

In droppable, as others said, show is not being called correctly (refer to the jq docs). Anyway I'm attaching code that appends the dragged element into the ui-layout...That is what I've used clone for in the past, not sure exactly what you are trying to do :)

```
 jQuery(function() {
  jQuery(".component").draggable({

    helper: function () { return  $(this).clone().css({'zIndex':5,'background-color':'red'}); },
    cursor:  'move'
  });

  jQuery('.ui-layout-center').droppable({ 
      accept:  '.component'  ,
      drop:  function (event, ui) {$(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone()); }
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Mistake is

*You are Using Show() without proper syntax

Try This Another Logic as by Len(Modified)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".component").draggable({
            helper: function () { return  $(this).clone().appendTo('body').css({'zIndex':5,'background-color':'red'}); },
            cursor:  'move'
        });
        jQuery('.ui-layout-center').droppable({
            accept:  '.component'  ,
            drop:  function (event, ui) {$(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone()); }//This is to append the clone in '.ui-layout-center' when dropped
        }); 
    });
```